# iOS why does Passbook not show the Geofencing indicator?

Tags: ios, passbook, geofencing

Is Passbook not using geofencing (specifically CLRegion Monitoring), or is it just that Apple allows it to not show the Geofencing indicator (hollow location indicator on top right)?

Answer (score 0):

Passbook location monitoring is bundled in the **Location-Based Alerts** System Service which is not showing the Status Bar Icon indicator.